# What to do about extremely slow TS type inference for IntelliSense with recursive and nested types?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, types, intellisense

I try to create types for a normalized version of `schema.org` JSON-LD types. These are provided by the [schema-dts package](https://github.com/google/schema-dts). This is just one example of a package that exports **many types that additionally are deeply nested and connected with eachother**. Therefore, when saying something like

```
import type * as schemaOrg from 'schema-dts';
const restaurant: schemaOrg.Restaurant = {
 // ...
}
```

and then using IntelliSense e.g. to show the properties in `restaurant`, it already takes more time than usual, but just a few milliseconds, so that is not a problem.

However, I am trying to create a slightly normalized version of such types, and I have typed them as follows:

```
type PrimitiveValue = undefined | null | boolean | number | string;
type Flattened<A> = A extends (infer E)[] ? Flattened<E> : A;
type IdReference = {'@id': string;};
type PreprocessedSchemaOrgValue<TValue> = Exclude<TValue, IdReference | schemaOrg.Role>;
type NormalizedSchemaOrgValue<T> =
  T extends any ? // This is for associative distribution
    T extends schemaOrg.Role ? never :
    T extends schemaOrg.Boolean ? boolean :
    T extends `${number}` ? number :
    T extends ((infer E)[] | readonly (infer E)[]) ? Flattened<NormalizedSchemaOrgValue<E>>[] :
    T extends {'@type': string | string[]} ? {
      [k in keyof T]: k extends '@id' |'@type' ? T[k] :
        T[k] extends PrimitiveValue
          ? Exclude<T[k], undefined>[] | undefined
          : Exclude<NormalizedSchemaOrgValue<T[k]>, undefined>[] | undefined // This recursion probably causes the problem
      ;
    } :
    T extends IdReference ? never :
    PreprocessedSchemaOrgValue<T>
  : never
;
```

Note the recursion. This works basically, but when I now try

```
const restaurant: NormalizedSchemaOrgValue<schemaOrg.Restaurant> = {
  // ...
};
```

using IntelliSense (in VSCode) here takes *excessively* long (10-20 seconds maybe). You can test it for yourself in the [TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/N9n1qm). This is not too surprising **due to the recursion in combination with the nestedness**.
[image: IntelliSenseloading]

Is there anything that can be done about that?

Comment: Your playground link is broken. In the future, consider using https://tsplay.dev/ to shorten playground URLs.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I'm going to be able to wade through this if it relies on a third-party library.  Could you provide a self-contained example where everything is in plain text in the body of your question instead of imported? If so, please mention @jcalz in your reply so I'm notified. If not, then, uh... good luck! ‍♂️

Comment: @caTS: I have updated the playground link and used tsplay.dev now. I do not really understand why it was broken, I had tested it beforehand.

Comment: @jcalz: I would like to, but for the problem to occur you need dozens of long data types that are nested and linked to each other. Hard to realize with a self-contained example... Also, Google's `schema-dts` is just _one_ (although an important) example of such a data type collection; the problem does not depend on that particular library.

Comment: [Excluding string](https://tsplay.dev/WKOR8W) makes it a lot faster...

Comment: By the way, you should use `T extends readonly (infer E)[]`, as mutable arrays are assignable to readonly arrays.

Answer (score 0):

For why this works is beyond me, but excluding `string` before normalizing the schema seems to improve speeds drastically:

```
// zoom!
const restaurant: NormalizedSchemaOrgValue<Exclude<schemaOrg.Restaurant, string>> = {
  
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKOR8W)